# Looking for a speaker diarization library that can be installed on mac

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, toolkit, speech

I have tried to install the following libraries/toolkits and all have given build errors on mac running mavericks:
(1) ALIZE
(2) bob.spear
(3) SHoUT
(4) spkr_diar_ib_rel

I have additionally spent time using LIUM and voiceid, and they do not work well enough on the audio files I am using, which are low-quality and consist of conversation.

Can you recommend any software that can performed (a) speech segmentation and (b) speaker recognition (the combination of which apparently constitute speaker diarization)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALIZE is highly recommended. It's a state-of-the-art speaker recognition open source toolkit. Our lab use it for many years and it's very useful in speaker recognition research. As the [ALIZE_3.0 paper](http://www1.i2r.a-star.edu.sg/~alarcher/Publications_files/ALIZE_3.pdf) described, it support Mac OS very well. You say that you have problems in installing it, maybe you can show your detailed build errors and someone may help you.